# Python or SQL? Split data from column to populate new column

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I have a column in SQL Server with data that I want to split out delineated by "/" to populate into a new column. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with SQL Server or if it'd be easier to use Python.

This is a sample of the data now:

| Contract_ID | Contract_Quote_Number | Contract_SO_PO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1469 | COL 386986 / SO 590685 | null |
| 1471 | COL 387554 / SO 590613 | null |
| 1472 | COL 387527 / SO 590650 | null |
| 1473 | COL 387638 / SO 590658 | null |

This is what I want it to look like:

| Contract_ID | Contract_Quote_Number | Contract_SO_PO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1469 | COL 386986 | SO 590685 |
| 1471 | COL 387554 | SO 590613 |
| 1472 | COL 387527 | SO 590650 |
| 1473 | COL 387638 | SO 590658 |

So far in Python I've been able to pull the data into a CSV file and have sort of figured out how to split it. The problem I'm running into is that once I have it split properly I'll then have to re-write the csv data to SQL Server. I don't know if that's possible.

My python code so far (I'm writing to an empty csv file because as far as I know it's hard to overwrite a column in csv):

```
import csv
'''getting the col info'''
with open("C:\wamp64\www\SO_PO_Query.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile) # Create a new reader
    next(reader) # Skip the first row
    col = [row[1].split("/")[0] for row in reader]

print(col)

'''
writing 'col' to empty csv file

This works but it writes a space between each value
'''
rows = zip(col)
with open("C:\wamp64\www\empty.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I think the better question is why a "combined" value is stored in this column in the first place. Might be a much safer or effective or efficient approach to change the process that populates this table / column rather than "fix" it afterwards. Consider the use of computed columns (or a view) if that works.

Comment: I'm working on fixing that issue currently but I want to be able to go back and change the old records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL isn't great at string manipulation, and Python (or any procedural language) is generally better at this. But a single split is fairly simple.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Contract_ID,
  Contract_Quote_Number = ISNULL(LEFT(t.Contract_Quote_Number, v.slash - 1), t.Contract_Quote_Number),
  Contract_SO_PO = SUBSTRING(t.Contract_Quote_Number, v.slash + 3, LEN(t.Contract_Quote_Number))
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' / ', t.Contract_Quote_Number), 0)
) ) v(slash);
```

- `NULLIF` ensures the query does not fail if the value is not found

Answer (score 0):

One more method.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Contract_ID int primary key, Contract_Quote_Number VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Contract_ID, Contract_Quote_Number) VALUES
(1469, 'COL 386986 / SO 590685'),
(1471, 'COL 387554 / SO 590613'),
(1472, 'COL 387527 / SO 590650'),
(1473, 'COL 387638 / SO 590658');

SELECT Contract_ID
    , Contract_Quote_Number = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
    , Contract_SO_PO = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('["' + REPLACE(Contract_Quote_Number, ' / ', '","') + '"]')) AS B(S);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| Contract_ID | Contract_Quote_Number | Contract_SO_PO |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------+
|        1469 | COL 386986            | SO 590685      |
|        1471 | COL 387554            | SO 590613      |
|        1472 | COL 387527            | SO 590650      |
|        1473 | COL 387638            | SO 590658      |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy with charindex:

```
select * 
 , left(Contract_Quote_Number
          , charindex(Contract_Quote_Number,'/')-1) 
 , right(Contract_Quote_Number
          , len(Contract_Quote_Number) -  charindex(Contract_Quote_Number,'/') - 1 ) from table
```